# Refreshing the "Edit Email Settings" page doesn't refresh the email field if previously it was cleared (without pressing save button)

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, profile-edit

1. Go to Edit [Email Settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current).
2. Clear the email field, but don't press "Save".
3. Refresh the page. Field will be empty.

Only if you open another page and after that open Edit Email Settings page again, the input will be not empty.

**Firefox 61.0.2.**

Comment: No repo for me on Vivaldi, refreshing the page restores the default address.

Comment: @MarkKirby I use Firefox 61.0.2.

Comment: Just checked on Firefox and indeed the address was not restored, strange but it does seem to be browser specific.

Comment: That probably has to do with the way your browser stores cookies, but it might also be that SE stores Firefox cookies differently, and they save wrong. In both cases, though, you would expect to see other cookie-related problems. Have you noticed anything else, like having to sign in frequently or other settings not saving?

Comment: Never mind about logging in, that is Google related.